# $f\in L^1(0,1)$, $f\ge 0$, $f$ continuous on $(0,1)$. Does then $\lim_{x\to 0}xf(x) = 0$?

Tags: real-analysis

The title says it. Again: I have a function $f\ge 0$ on $(0,1)$ that is $L^1$ and continuous (possibly not at zero). Is it then true that $xf(x)\to 0$ as $x\to 0$?

What I did: I put $g(x) = xf(x)\ge 0$. Then
$$
\frac 1y\int_0^yg(x)\,dx = \frac 1y\int_0^yxf(x)\,dx\le\frac 1y\int_0^yyf(x)\,dx = \int_0^yf(x)\,dx\,\to\,0.
$$
But I am unable to infer from here that $\lim_{x\to 0}g(x) = 0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not true. As you know you cannot take $f(x)=1/x$ as that is not $L^1$. But you can zero this function out on "most" of the domain to get an $L^1$ function, while still keeping it equal to $1/x$ at points arbitrarily close to $x=0$.

To do that, it suffices to find sequences $a_n,b_n$ such that:

- $0<a_{n+1}<b_{n+1}<a_n<b_n<1$
- $\sum \ln(b_n/a_n)$ is convergent
- $a_n \to 0$.

Then take $f(x)=\frac{\chi_{\bigcup (a_n,b_n)}(x)}{x}$. The resulting function has discontinuities but these can be smoothed out without destroying the essential properties (except, of course, for the one at $x=0$).

I think one such sequence is $a_n=2^{-n},b_n=2^{-n}+4^{-n}$.

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes, this sequence does it.